# ERROR - JavaFX Does Not Open Second Parent Screen if Maximized (true)

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, stage

I have an example of parent and child stages, when opening the program the primaryStage is maximized, minimization (when with maximized screen mode enabled) and reopening only pull one of the child stages of the stage, the other is hidden. How should I work this kind of problem?

Note: I need the daughters to be initStyle (StageStyle.UTILITY) to concatenate the stages in just one icon in S.O.

```html
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class LotsaStages extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX App");
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        stage.show();

        Stage stage2 = new Stage();
        stage2.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage2.initOwner(primaryStage);
        stage2.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that. When clicking on the minimize symbol of the `primaryStage` and reopening it both panels (`stage` & `stage2`) are visible for me.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  If it’s Linux, what desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I use linux mint, I will do a test on windows